# Mysql_connect error

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a problem with my mysql-connect code after I moved a database (I know the database is not the problem) from one server to another:

```
<?php 
    mysql_connect("host", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());

    $query = "select COUNT(Motstander), ROUND(AVG(Serveess),2),ROUND(AVG(Dobbeltfeil),2), ROUND(AVG(1serveinn),2), ROUND(AVG(1servevinn),2), ROUND(AVG(2serveinn),2), ROUND(AVG(2servevinn),2), ROUND(AVG(Servicegamevinn),2), ROUND(AVG(Breakpointsvinn),2), ROUND(AVG(Lengde),2) from Statistikk where Navn='Melanie Stokke'";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        echo $row['COUNT(Motstander)']. " kamper fra 4. april 2016):</b> <br/>". "Serveess: ". $row['ROUND(AVG(Serveess),2)']. "<br/>Dobbeltfeil: ". $row['ROUND(AVG(Dobbeltfeil),2)']. "<br/>". "1. serve inne: ". $row['ROUND(AVG(1serveinn),2)']. "% ". "<br/>1. serve seiersprosent: ". $row['ROUND(AVG(1servevinn),2)']. "% ". "<br/>2. serve inne: ". $row['ROUND(AVG(2serveinn),2)']. "%". "<br/>2. serve seiersprosent: ". $row['ROUND(AVG(2servevinn),2)']. "%". "<br/>Servicegame seiersprosent: ". $row['ROUND(AVG(Servicegamevinn),2)']. "%". "<br/>Antall breakpoints: ". $row['ROUND(AVG(Breakpointsvinn),2)']. "<br/>Lengde: ". $row['ROUND(AVG(Lengde),2)']. " min. <br/>";

    }
?>
```

It dosent work at http://www.tennis-norge.com/resultateter-melanie-stokke/, but work at http://wwww.oddseren.com/stokkeres with this code:

```
<?php 
    mysql_connect("host", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());

    $query = "select COUNT(Motstander), ROUND(AVG(Serveess),2),ROUND(AVG(Dobbeltfeil),2), ROUND(AVG(1serveinn),2), ROUND(AVG(1servevinn),2), ROUND(AVG(2serveinn),2), ROUND(AVG(2servevinn),2), ROUND(AVG(Servicegamevinn),2), ROUND(AVG(Breakpointsvinn),2), ROUND(AVG(Lengde),2) from Statistikk where Navn='Melanie Stokke'";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    round($query, 0);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        echo $row['COUNT(Motstander)']. " kamper fra 4. april 2016):</b> <br/>". "Serveess: ". $row['ROUND(AVG(Serveess),2)']. "<br/>Dobbeltfeil: ". $row['ROUND(AVG(Dobbeltfeil),2)']. "<br/>". "1. serve inne: ". $row['ROUND(AVG(1serveinn),2)']. "% ". "<br/>1. serve seiersprosent: ". $row['ROUND(AVG(1servevinn),2)']. "% ". "<br/>2. serve inne: ". $row['ROUND(AVG(2serveinn),2)']. "%". "<br/>2. serve seiersprosent: ". $row['ROUND(AVG(2servevinn),2)']. "%". "<br/>Servicegame seiersprosent: ". $row['ROUND(AVG(Servicegamevinn),2)']. "%". "<br/>Antall breakpoints: ". $row['ROUND(AVG(Breakpointsvinn),2)']. "<br/>Lengde: ". $row['ROUND(AVG(Lengde),2)']. " min. <br/>";

    }
?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Suggestion 1, stop using the deprecated and removed in latter versions of php MySQL library

Comment: @Dagon I´ve tried other connections without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have user `tennis_norge_com` on the second server.

Error 500 can result from a connection error to mysql.

You can have more information by adding at start of script.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

One tips... it's not a good idea to give login/password in a public post on internet.

Comment: I have another codeline the works fine with the same user when I remover the code in the question.

Thanks for the error_reporting tips. It is something with the login, event though it works, and thanks for the heads up. Allready changed :)